# Cant' Grab WordPress Built-in Posts Through Loop

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Using WordPress 3.7.1 I am trying to display all Regular Post on my created page lest say TestPage. Here are the steps I took to do this:

**1-** Generate a Custom Page Template called:`Test Page` and loaded by following code
**2-** Generate a Page Called TestPage based on `Test Page` Template

after updating the page I am not getting any of Post on the page while I have already generated some!

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Test Page
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <h1><?php the_title() ;?></h1>  
    <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <p>Sorry, this page does not exist</p>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

he abouve code actually is loading the page whit title and content of the  TestPage and not by Posts!Can you please let me know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

You must understand the difference between post and page.

A page is associated with a template. Through code, you can lists posts or other pages using this page /template.

The above code will only display the **Page** data

You don't want to create many pages using the same tempalte in order to show different data with the same tempalte. Instead you create posts and give them a category.

Then you can fetch these posts and display them in the same way asthe test-page.

You can either use [get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) or [wp_get_recent_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts).
Or, if you really want to list pages, use [wp_list_pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages).

Besides that, you should look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages and http://codex.wordpress.org/Posts